# Pentaho to convert tree structure data

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle

I have a stream of data from a CSV. It is a flat structured database.

E.g.:

```
a,b,c,d
a,b,c,e
a,b,f
```

This essentially transforms into:

```
 Node id,Nodename,parent id,level
 100, a , 0 , 1
 200, b , 100 , 2
 300, c , 200 , 3
 400, d , 300 , 4
 500, e , 300 , 4
 600, f , 200 , 3
```

Can this be done using Pentaho? I have gone through the transformation steps. But nothing strikes me as usable for this purpose. Please let me know if there is any step that I may have missed.

Comment: have you tried using **Row Normaliser** step ? Check this [wiki](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Row+Normaliser)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CSV file contains graph or tree definition. The output format is rich (`node_id` needs to be generated, `parent_id` needs to be resolved, `level` needs to be set). There are few issues you will face when processing this kind of CSV file in Pentaho Data Integration:

Data loading & processing:

- Rows do not have same length (sometimes 4 nodes, sometimes 3 node).
- Load whole rows. And then split rows to nodes and process one node per record stream item.
- You can calculate output values in the same step as where the nodes are split.

Solution Steps:

1. **CSV file input:** Load data from CSV. *Settings: No header row; Delimiter = ';'; One output column named `rowData`*
2. **Modified Java Script Value:** Split `rowData` to `nodes` and calculate output values: `nodeId, nodeName, parentId, nodeLevel` [See the code below]
3. **Sort rows:** Sort rows by `nodeName`. `[a,b,c,d,a,b,c,e,a,b,f >> a,a,a,b,b,c,c,d,e,f]`
4. **Unique rows:** Delete duplicate rows by `nodeName`. `[a,a,a,b,b,c,c,d,e,f >> a,b,c,d,e,f]`
5. **Text file output:** Write out results.

Modified Java Script Value **Code**:

```js
function writeRow(nodeId, nodeName, parentId, nodeLevel){
    newRow = createRowCopy(getOutputRowMeta().size());
    var rowIndex = getInputRowMeta().size();

    newRow[rowIndex++] = nodeId;
    newRow[rowIndex++] = nodeName;
    newRow[rowIndex++] = parentId;
    newRow[rowIndex++] = nodeLevel;

    putRow(newRow);
}

var nodeIdsMap = {
    a: "100",
    b: "200",
    c: "300",
    d: "400",
    e: "500",
    f: "600",
    g: "700",
    h: "800",
}

// rowData from record stream (CSV input step)
var nodes = rowData.split(",");

for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
    var nodeId = nodeIdsMap[nodes[i]];
    var parentNodeId = (i == 0) ? "0" : nodeIdsMap[nodes[i-1]];
    var level = i + 1;
    writeRow(nodeId, nodes[i], parentNodeId, level);
}
trans_Status = SKIP_TRANSFORMATION;
```

Modified Java Script Value **Field Settings**:

- **Fieldname; Type; Replace value'Fieldname' or 'Rename to'**
- nodeId; String; N
- nodeName; String; N
- parent_id; String; N
- nodeLevel; String; N

Comment: be careful that you're not checking that parent_id is well defined. If the input had something like "a,b,c" followed by "a,c,d", you would take b to be parent of c in row 1, but a as the parent in row 2; It should be checked that each node only has 1 parent in the original data, which cannot be assumed to be well defined, and issue an alert if not.

Comment: Yes. You are absolutely right. The solution assumes that input tree is defined correctly. If you would like to check this, add `Analytic Query` step (right after `Sort rows`). Get `LAG '1' BACKWARD row` and compare its values with actual row values, if they have the same `nodeName` (use `Filter rows` step).

Comment: Thanks a lot . I ll implement this and let you know if it worked out . !